certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1002)
I have a problem with connecting via ssl.
The very essence of the connection:
I wrote a model in Python and I need to transfer its metrics as a result to mlflow - which is located on the server.
The connection code is non-trivial - set the environment variables and write the name of the model on which you want to remember the experiment.
But when I try to connect, it complains about certificates.
API request to ... failed with exception HTTPSConnectionPool(host='...', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: ... (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate ( _ssl.c:1002)')))

In previous questions people write to install local verification files - but I already have them and it doesn’t help. Could this error be related to unconfigured verification on the mlflow server itself?
Here's the code:
os.environ['MLFLOW_TRACKING_USER'] = settings.MLFLOW_TRACKING_USER
os.environ['MLFLOW_TRACKING_PASSWORD'] = settings.MLFLOW_TRACKING_PASSWORD
os.environ['MLFLOW_S3_ENDPOINT_URL'] = settings.MLFLOW_S3_ENDPOINT_URL
os.environ['MLFLOW_TRACKING_URI'] = settings.MLFLOW_TRACKING_URI

try:
     mlflow.set_experiment("factoring_client_predict_fact")
     mlflow.start_run()
     # code for training a model or other operations with mlflow
except Exception as e:
     print(f"An error occurred while establishing a connection: {e}")



solved the problem in two ways

added local company certificates (intermediate and root)

Relying on https://www.mlflow.org/docs/
I found an environ variable - MLFLOW_TRACKING_INSECURE_TLS (analogous to verify = False)


Syntax:
os.environ['MLFLOW_TRACKING_INSECURE_TLS'] = 'true' 

